# Easiest way to pass info out of a Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am trying to use Selenium's WebDriver to automate the testing of a security tool I'm developing. Specifically, I am attempting to inject js payloads into a HTML page via reflected XSS. In order to test the fitness of the payloads, I need to verify that the scripts actually run.

I have been largely successful in doing this by having XSS payloads call a specific function which passes information to my python program with one of the following methods:

1. Creating new elements in the DOM and finding them with the WebDriver python API (find_elements_by_class_name, etc.)
2. Setting the window title in js and reading it via driver.title
3. Creating dialogs/prompts in js and handling them via driver.switch_to_alert()

However the above are all pretty hacky and slow (<s>especially method #1 if the desired element does not exist</s> I'm stupid and had my implicit wait really high, but I still don't like the method of creating dom elements to pass strings). Also, the last option fails pretty consistently if there are multiple alerts.

I wanted to retrieve variable values via driver.execute_script(script) however my scripts seem unable to actually read values, as stuff like 'return window.name' always returns None. That being said, I don't expect execute_script() to be the fastest method, since it has to perform a lot of overhead in executing said script.

**What is the fastest way to pass runtime information from inside a browser context to the controlling python program?** I don't need to send much info, maybe a few kb at the most, so a cookie value could suffice but the browser's URL probably wouldn't.

Comment: So you are trying to read a cookie value and other information of the sort from the loaded page right?

Comment: I am trying to check whether or not a given script actually executed. The script can do anything from setting a cookie value, changing the DOM, changing the BOM, or even sending AJAX requests. The script's contents are up to me to decide, and all I want to know is a good way to determine if the script runs in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pickle, requests
import selenium.webdriver 


driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://google.com")

# getting page title with js
print driver.execute_script("""
    return document.title;
    """)

# add a random cookie
driver.add_cookie({'name':'test', 'value': 'test'})

# save cookies on a pickle file
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))

driver.close()

# then later open the cookies with
loaded_cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))

print loaded_cookies
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood. Passing information is not an issue, but rather the speed and efficiency is in question. I was trying to see if there is a better way other than changing the DOM/cookies/BOM and reading it via the driver. Furthermore, if I wanted the cookie values, I wouldn't save them to file just to read them again :)

Comment: Hi @SyntaxTerror! From what I've seen so far, getting the data from the driver is the usual way to go. Regarding performance on Selenium, there are some other things you might like to consider. Did you check the PhantomJS driver? Can you give some more details on your needs? Do you have a situation with many pages to process? Is there a log in situation? What do you want to do? Am I right that you'd like to have the DOM after javascript?

Comment: I'm looking at PhantomJS now and it looks like something I should investigate... I do not need the DOM after the js executes. Ideally this script will make thousands of requests, keeping each response only long enough for pertinent javascript to execute (as some DOM elements may not be included in the response but rather are fetched asynchronously).